# Training loop for a WGAN returning losses of zero on our custom Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am currently training a WGAN on a custom database having gotten usable results with MNIST, we tried to work with our own images. I am currently using the exact same code. (Train a discriminator n times, then a generator). Calculate losses etc etc. I only made a numeric change to the generator due to the padding. )

The initial code being run was

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
        start = time.time()
        disc_loss = 0
        gen_loss = 0

        for images in train_dataset:
            disc_loss += train_discriminator(images)

            if disc_optimizer.iterations.numpy() % n_critic == 0:
                gen_loss += train_generator()

        print('Time for epoch {} is {} sec - gen_loss = {}, disc_loss = {}'.format(epoch + 1, time.time() - start, gen_loss / batch_size, disc_loss / (batch_size*n_critic)))

        if epoch % save_interval == 0:
            save_imgs(epoch, generator, seed)
```

Because of errors with expected dimension when I run it with our numpies

```
Expected ndim=4, got ndim=3
```

Pointing to training of our discriminator. I solved these errors by making the following changes:

```
for images in train_dataset:
            images=np.expand_dims(images, axis=0)
            images=images/255.
            #images=images.resize
            disc_loss += train_discriminator(images)
```

This solved the issue to start the training process but I noticed a few other issues.

Firstly, the loss values after the first epoch we set to 0 and the actual generated images, never changed after the first time I displayed it. The final issue was the training times seemed to be way too fast. There is no way epoch 2 trained in 0.0002 seconds and so on

```
Time for epoch 1 is 613.6920039653778 sec - gen_loss = -0.7189221382141113, disc_loss = -1.3103094100952148
Time for epoch 2 is 0.00022411346435546875 sec - gen_loss = 0, disc_loss = 0
```

Has anyone else dealt with something similar or is there a loop error that I can't pick up on?

Comment: Did you check the model weights after epoch 1? And you don't have a problem with your loop, your loop seems fine. I would recommend checking it once in the inner loop, whether it is entering the inner for loop after your first epoch.

Comment: I Will look into this. Not too sure how to go about it. I will look into it

Comment: Add a print statement to check how many times it iterates in the second inner loop and save the model weights after every epoch. then read the weights from the hdf5 to see whether they exploded or saturated to 0. But it will be hard to tell unless I know about the network configuration